# excluding byte[] from serialization of XMLEncoder

Tags: java, arrays, transient, xmlencoder

The problem is how to except an `byte[]` from serialization of XMLEncoder, but i need to save this field to DB. I have a Object

```
public class MyClass1 implements Serializable {
 some properties ...
 private  byte[] a01_14_01_content;
 getters and setters ...
}
```

and Encoder:

```
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
public class MyEncoder{ 
...
public byte[] getBytes() {
    XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(baos);
    e.writeObject(answer);
    e.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
}
```

I need to serialize all fields except array fields. 
`transient`  modifier for property doesn't work;
`@Transient` annotation on on get method doesn't work;
`@XMLTransient` annotation  on property doesn't work.
It's so simple, but I need help of community!

Comment: what `@Transient` annotation did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to use  `@java.beans.Transient` annotaion on get method instead @Transient. 
In my case `import javax.persistence.*` caused a "bug" ))

```
public class MyClass1 implements Serializable {
 some properties ...
 private  byte[] a01_14_01_content;

 @javax.beans.Transient //not @Transient
 public byte[] getA01_14_01_content() {
 return a01_14_01_content;
 } 
//getters and setters ...
}
```